# Why don't we write var or val before method parameter names in scala?

Tags: scala

Why don't we write var or val before method parameter names in Scala?

E.g., a function definition:

```
def printname(name: String) = println(name)
```

Comment: What additional information would that provide to the compiler?  The compiler already knows that they are parameters.

Comment: Because it's not required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because they are `val`s, and that's it. So no need to specify it.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed scala will complain if you put either var or val before a parameter identifier in methods/functions; it is demanding that parameters should implicitly be val.

(Of course the situation is different for primary constructor parameters)

Comment: This is an unsatisfying answer, given that in Java you get a mutable local by default (and Scala caters to Java, and they say local mutables are OK). Indeed, Scala function params could work just like ctor params, especially since they try to make ctors uniform with defs otherwise, except that ctors always have a param list, so that you would say `f(var i)` just in case you wanted to assign to it. Ctors already complain about anomalies like `x(var i: =>Int`. The question is why, not "what happens if I...?"

Comment: @som-snytt Primary constructor parameters can be `val`s or `var`s _as class members_, not as local variables (which would be the only way possible for function parameters). This is simply a shortcut for avoiding duplication like `class Foo(_bar: Int) { var bar: Int = _bar }`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes, why can't I avoid this duplication: `def f(i: Int) = { var j = i; j += 1; j }`? It is more benign than ctor var perhaps. (People recently have said class param name shadowing super induces idioms like `Foo(_bar: Int) extends Bar(_bar)`. As an example of less benign.)